# Need more clarification offset concept while using scrolltop

Tags: jquery, css

I am using scrollTop .I take some example from google .I am facing one problem in this line.

```
 $content.scrollTop(
        $box.offset().top - $content.offset().top + $content.scrollTop());
```

My confusion is that this :  `$box.offset().top - $content.offset().top` this value is always be same.?

But when I print on console it print the different values.
When I read from google about offset it say it display the relative position from document.

**Secondly:**

Some one use clear :both .when I read it say it display below the floating element .
can you please give one example to differentiate. 
http://jsfiddle.net/TnTj9/12/